Workflow that can send Existing Gmail Emails to OneNote based on certain criteria
Is there a workflow that can send existing emails from Gmail account to OneNote based on a certain criterion? I am aware of IFTTT or Power Automate flow. But those work or gets triggered when a new email is received. But I want to send existing emails to OneNote based on the sender.
Is that possible? Please help.
